# "SyntaxError: return not in function" when I use "javascript: return false;" in <a href></a>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

This issue has bugged me for hours and I can't seem to solve it.  It works in one form and then not another.  My problem is this code:

```
<a href="javascript: return false;" name='btnAddressFind1' id='btnAddressFind1' class="btn ahrefbutton">
    Find Address
</a>
.
.
.
<div id="divAddress1Picker"></div>
```

A React script is bound to this element:

```
if ( document.getElementById('divAddress1Picker') ) {
    if ( document.getElementById('btnAddressFind1') ) {
        document.getElementById('btnAddressFind1').onclick = function(ev) {
            var postcode = document.getElementById('txtAddressPostcode1').value;
            if (postcode) {
                axios.get("http://mydomain/ajax/postcode/lookup?postcode=" + postcode)
                    .then( (response) => {
                        ReactDOM.render(<PostcodeLookup postcode={response.data} field={1} />, document.getElementById('divAddress1Picker') );
                    } )
                    .catch(error => console.log(error));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click elem btnAddressFind1 I get the following error in the browser inspector console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: return not in function                                  return false;:1:1
```

I've tried adding it to a function:

```
function myFunc() {
    return false;
}
```

... and when the `<a></a>` is clicked the page is re-rendereds with a single line of text 'return false;'

Has anyone come across this before?  Any help would be appreciated.  This is annoying beyond frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<a href='javascript:;' .....></a>`